# Modelling best practices with Grakn

Tags: entity-relationship, data-modeling, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I've looked at how to do data modelling and have some questions in regards to the use of roles specifically in Grakn.

Let's take a simple case. I have a Company, and that Company can be a Distributor, Supplier, Customer, or any such combination. Company A could be a distributor and a customer at the same time.

If I use a relational database, I would have a table for CompanyS and then tables for SupplierS, CustomerS, etc, which then would reference the Company table.

However, I want to start with a Company and know what roles it is playing without having to create these extra tables. So that in my application I can know that a company is both a distributor and a supplier in a single query.

There's a few ways I can think how to do it, but as I feel this problem domain is so common there must be some best practices for modelling these concepts.

So I am looking for common patterns or strategies to model and name certain entity roles. I am using Grakn. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you mean to ask for general rules of thumb for choosing roles. Choosing roles is also caught up in choosing the naming for your relations, entities and attributes. In the case given, `company` is ubiquitously modelled as an entity, but there are plenty of examples where you may realise that you had the naming for an entity/relation/role mixed up.

Try this for general guidance:

Entity: Should be capable of its own existence in the world. Can be an abstract concept. Use abstract nouns (`company`, `religion`), collective nouns, common nouns.

Relation: Should have existence dependent upon the existence of its role players. Use abstract nouns (`marriage`, `membership`, `hierarchy`) and verbal nouns (`authorship`, `ownership`, ).

Role: Should describe a behaviour within the context of a relation. You can try using this sentence: A [entity] behaves like a [role] in a [relation]. For example a `station` behaves like a `stop` in a `train-route`. Should use nouns.

Attributes: Should describe a **quantity only** e.g. `name` (string), `age` (long), `colour` (string), `is-green` (boolean), `verbose` (boolean), `is-running` (boolean), `score` (double). Typically nouns or verbs. Anything goes if it describes a value well.

If you struggle to find a noun, use a name that ends with a noun, but prepend with a descriptive term, like `authored-book`.

Answer (score 0):

At times it may be easier to think of relations in terms of verbs too -- as long as they are gerund tense. For example:

```
faceting sub relation,
   relates facet-assignment,
   relates assigned-facet.

listing sub relation,
   relates list-assignment,
   relates assigned-list.
```